# How to redraw tree (jstree)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

I'm using jQuery library ([jstree](http://www.jstree.com/)) to draw a tree. It draws the tree the first time - when the page loads. But when I press a button to update the tree data, it fails and the div becomes blank. Below is the code which refreshes the data.

```
$('#jsstree').html("");

   jQuery("jsstree").jstree("destroy");
    $('#jsstree').jstree({
        'core': {
            'data': [
               { "id": "ajson1", "parent": "#", "text": "Simple root node" },
               { "id": "ajson2", "parent": "#", "text": "Root node 2" },
               { "id": "ajson3", "parent": "ajson2", "text": "Child 1" },
               { "id": "ajson4", "parent": "ajson2", "text": "Child 2" },
            ]
        }
    });
```

Comment: I think `jQuery("jsstree")` should be `$('#jsstree')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like that:

```
tree.jstree("refresh");
```